# How to properly integrate PyQt4 and Twisted?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, twisted

Currently, the code to run my pyqt app, which uses twisted, is the following:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, reactor, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.reactor = reactor
        self.resize(250,150)
        self.move(300,300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Simple')

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        self.reactor.stop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    import qt4reactor
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    qt4reactor.install()
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    window = MainWindow(reactor)
    window.show()
    reactor.runReturn()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This snippet of code is something I found online with the qt4reactor documentation. My application runs fine, but it does not close properly. When I exit the app, something keeps running. Pressing ctrl+c to force the event to close causes a python.exe has stopped working error.

The goal is to get the application to close properly. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. In general, I'm a pyqt and twisted amateur. Any help understanding what I'm doing with this snippet of code would also be incredibly useful as I would love to understand what I'm doing wrong :)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a minimal test.ui to your question?  The example isn't complete without it.

Comment: Hi Jean, thanks for helping! I updated the code with a very minimal ui, which still doesn't close properly. It might be worth noting that when I force the code to stop, it now stops "cleanly". It no longer throws errors, such as python.exe has stopped working. However, it still doesn't close on its own.

Comment: Thanks.  Example is now a very good one.  Unfortunately I can't yet reproduce your observed behavior.  When I click the close control on the window, it closes and the process exits cleanly!  I tested against Python 2.7.14, Twisted 16.6.0, qt4reactor 1.6, PyQt4 4.11.4+dfsg-2build2, libqtgui4 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 (Ubuntu 17.10)

Answer (score -1):

Attach a handler to your Qt exit signal which stops the reactor (via `reactor.stop()`).

Comment: I've tried that before to no success. I've edited the main question with more details.